# Joining tables in a Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to be able to return some data from a controller so that I can create a graph in JavaScript using the gon gem.

I have two models:

```
account:  id[PK, int], name[string], credit[boolean], active[boolean]
balance: id[PK, int], account_id[FK, int], balance[decimal], date[date]

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :balances
end

class Balance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
end
```

For a given date `@latestDate`, I want to be able to return the account[name], account[credit] and balance[balance].

Currently, with the code below I can return the `balance` object at a given date but how can I return the joined `account` data as well so that I also have the account[name] and account[credit].

Code:

```
  def statement
    @dates = Balance.select("distinct(date)").order('date desc')

    if (params[:date_id].blank?)
      if (Balance.count > 0)
        @latestDate = Balance.order('date desc').first.date
      else
        @latestDate = Date.current
      end
    else
      @latestDate = params[:date_id]
    end

    @summaryBalances = Balance.joins(:account).order('accounts.credit').where('date = :abc', {abc: @latestDate})

    gon.assets = @summaryBalances
  end
```

Comment: It's been a while since I've used ActiveRecord, but I believe that [includes](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes) is what you want. Similar to `join`, but it grabs the additional records when going to the database.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if the `account` records are stored with the `balances` in `@summaryBalances` or if you would have to specifically store them in another variable.

Comment: @RyanK If I change my code to `gon.assets = Balance.includes(:account)`, I still only return the balance data. I want to be able to return the account data within the same objects.

Answer (score 0):

To get account object, you should get through model's relation.

```
ex)
 @summaryBalances.each do |ba|
   account = ba.account.name
 end
```

If you want to avoid N+1 problem, you should use preload or include to precach account object.

Comment: That allows me to loop through and get the account names but how can I return the account names with '@summaryBalances`?

Comment: Did you try select ? http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-select